# Python Keras, same configurations gives different weights in different computers?

Tags: python, keras, recurrent-neural-network

I set up recurrent nerural network by using Keras. Although I use all same configurations(batch size, node, epoch, seed values etc.), get different model weights and so error values in different computers. I included following lines in my code to restart weights every run but I cannot solve the problem. What is the reason behind of this problem ?

Do python versions affect the result ?

```
    keras.backend.clear_session()
    model.reset_states()
    K.clear_session()
    del model
```

Thanks

Comment: do you have the same OS across machines?

Comment: Yes, in both computers Windows 10 is installed.

Comment: Do both the system have the same MP-architecture( 32/64 bit) and time-zone?

Comment: In that case, is your train-test sets the same? Can you give a few more details on the code and the set up?

Answer (score 0):

There are few possible reasons that may cause different weights:

- You didn't set `PYTHONHASHSEED` environment variable to the same value on these machines;
- You didn't set all the seeds that Python may use - a check if you're provide `numpy.random.seed()`, `random.seed()` and `tensorflow.set_random_seed()` (for TF 1.x) or `tensorflow.random.set_seed()` (for TF 2.x) with the same seeds on both machines.
- Check if you have installed the same versions of Keras on both machines.

Based on my experience, that's enough to get reproducible weights.